# Angular httpHeaders post menthod can't set parameters

Tags: angular, http-headers, httpclient, angular-httpclient

I am trying to get the authtoken from RestAPI using the below method.
The same url,Params and Headers returns me proper response from postman.
but in angular i am getting 401 unauthorized error.
please help me understand where i am doing wrong?
I am unable to understand why my headers are inside *lazyUpdate* object inside **httpHeaders**.

Thanks in advance.

```
login(loginData) {
const httpOptions = {
  headers:new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")).set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8").set("access-control-allow-credentials",'true'),
  params:new HttpParams().set('username', loginData.email).set('password', loginData.password).set('grant_type', 'grant_type')
}
this.http.post('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/oauth/token', httpOptions).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.saveToken(data);
    return true;
  },
  err => {
    alert('Invalid Credentials')
    return false;
  });
```

}

Please find the attached screenshot of the headers being sent from browser.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTTP header option as a third parameter in the post request.

```
login(loginData) { 

    let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            'Authorization' :  "Basic " + btoa("username:password"),
            'username': loginData.email,
            'password': loginData.password,
            'grant_type': 'grant_type' 
        }) 
    };

    this.http.post('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/oauth/token', {},  httpOptions).subscribe( data => {
        this.saveToken(data);
        return true;
    },
    err => {
        alert('Invalid Credentials')
        return false;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of a `post` method is the `body` payload of the HTTP call. You need to use the third parameter, which is for the options. You might pass a `null` value for the body parameter, but `post` calls without body are usually a sign of misuse.

```
this.http.post('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/oauth/token', null, httpOptions)
```